# how software interrupts are different than port IN/OUT ,

Tags: cpu

I am confused  with port mapping and ISR
since i am following an article which mentioned that hardware ports are mapped  to memory from 0x00000000 to 0x000003FF
now we can talk with microcontroller of that hardware using these port no using IN and OUT instructions ok

but what is ivt then mean i read ivt contain address of interrupt service routine 
 everthing is messed in mind

do when we use IN /OUTwith port no  cpu checks in ivt and how microcontrollers knows their number

Answer (score 0):

When hardware ports are mapped to memory location then this is called [Memory-Mapped IO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O).
Hardware is accessed by reading/writing data/commands in their registers. In Memory Mapped IO, instead of transmitting data/command to hardware registers, the cpu reads/writes signal/command/data at particular memory locations which are mapped to hardware registers. Therefore, communication between hardware and cpu happens via read/write to specific memory location.

When a hardware in installed it is given a set of fixed memory location for the purpose of Memory Mapped IO and these memory location are recorded. Also, every hardware has its ISR whose address is stored in IVT. Now when a particular hardware interrupts the cpu, the cpu finds the interrupting hardware's ISR address from the IVT. Once the cpu identifies with which hardware the communication (I/O) needs to be done then it communicate with that hardware via Memory Mapped IO by making use of the fixed memory locations which were allocated for that hardware.

Comment: then how different port no are given to microcontroller are they preassigned  by any authority as ports are assigned to application in networking or cpu assigned them as 0x60 is always assigned to keyboard status register